Trying to prove equivalence of combinatorial formula and nested summations
I’m sorry if this is a dumb problem, but I’m trying to get into mathematics and prove this but I’m only in 9th grade and haven’t found any sources on this:


Prove that $$ {n \choose r} = \overbrace{ \sum_{i=1}^{x-r+1} \left( \sum_{r=1}^i \left( \sum_{v=1}^r \left( \sum_{d=1}^v 1 \right) \right) \right) }^{r \text{ times summation}}$$


I have tested in desmos for values of x greater then r-1 but am not sure of how to algebraicly prove it

Please, write out the question instead of linking to a picture.

What is $x$ in your formula?

And why is $r$ used as a summation index?

Your posted question, as is, seems to have several obstacles that need to be cleared.  For one thing, I question your use of the variable $~x,~$ on the RHS, and I can't help but wonder if this is a typo on your part.  That is, since the LHS computes to a fixed number that is based solely on the constants $~n~$ and $~r,~$ in order to show that LHS = RHS, the RHS must also  compute to some fixed number, which is to be a function of the fixed constants $~n,~$ and $~r.~$ So, I wonder if $~x~$ should be replaced by some expression involving $~n.~$ ...see next comment

Similar to the previous comment, your use of the variable $~r,~$ on the RHS seems bizarre, since, based on the LHS, $~r~$ is some fixed constant.  ...see next comment

Finally, for what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

First, I'd like to clarify your question: you want to prove that
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\r\end{array}\right)=\sum_{k_1=1}^{n-r+1}\sum_{k_2=1}^{k_1}\sum_{k_3=1}^{k_2}\dots\sum_{k_{r-1}=1}^{k_{r-2}}\sum_{k_r=1}^{k_{r-1}}1$$
For $r=1$ and any $n\geqslant r$, you get
$$\sum_{k_1=1}^{n}1=n=\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\1\end{array}\right)$$
If, for some $R$, the formula holds for all couple $(n,r)$ with $r\leqslant R$ and $n\geqslant r$, then for all $n\geqslant R$, the Hockey stick identity yields
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}n+1\\R+1\end{array}\right)=\sum_{i=R}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}i\\R\end{array}\right)=\sum_{k_1=1}^{n-R+1} \left(\begin{array}{c}k_1+R-1 \\ R\end{array}\right)$$
By the induction hypothesis,
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}k_1+R-1\\R\end{array}\right)=\sum_{k_2=1}^{k_1}\sum_{k_3=1}^{k_2}\dots \sum_{k_{R}=1}^{k_{R-1}}\sum_{k_{R+1}=1}^{k_R}1$$
Hence,
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}n+1\\R+1\end{array}\right)=\sum_{k_1=1}^{(n+1)-(R+1)+1}\sum_{k_2=1}^{k_1}\sum_{k_3=1}^{k-2}\dots\sum_{k_{R}=1}^{k_{R-1}}\sum_{k_{R+1}=1}^{k_R}1$$
and by induction, your formula is true for all $(n,r)$ such that $n\geqslant r$.

The nested summation counts integer tuples $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_r)$ such that $1 \le x_1 \le x_2 \le \dots \le x_r \le n-r+1$.  Performing a change of variables
\begin{align}
y_1 &= x_1 - 1 \\
y_2 &= x_2 - x_1 \\
\vdots \\
y_r &= x_r - x_{r-1} \\
y_{r+1} &= n-r+1 - x_r \\
\end{align}
transforms the problem to counting nonnegative integer tuples
$(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_{r+1})$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{r+1} y_k = n-r$.  This count is well known to be $$\binom{(n-r)+(r+1)-1}{(r+1)-1} = \binom{n}{r}.$$  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics).
